# É possível um "Group by" por conteúdo da coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Estava a pensar, se era possível usar **GROUP BY** baseado na data de uma coluna, neste caso da coluna ANALYSIS que cria grupos sempre que encontra 0, invés da coluna.

```
       DIA        MES       YEAR      TODAY   TOMORROW   ANALYSIS      LIMIT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        19          9       2016        111        988          0        150 
        20          9       2016        988        853        853        150 
        21          9       2016        853        895        895        150 
        22          9       2016        895        776        776        150 
        23          9       2016        776        954          0        150 
        26          9       2016        954        968        968        150 
        27          9       2016        968        810        810        150 
        28          9       2016        810        937        937        150 
        29          9       2016        937        769        769        150 
        30          9       2016        769       1020          0        150 
         3         10       2016       1020        923        923        150 
         4         10       2016        923         32         32        150
```

O que pretendia era o seguinte, com base neste exemplo:

- Group 1 (Analysis): 0
- Group 2(Analysis): 853, 895,776,0
- Group 3(Analysis): 968,810,937,169,0
- ...

Comment: Por favor, traduza sua pergunta para o português.

Comment: ups, pensei que tava na english version, erro meu xd

Comment: É MySQL ou SQL Server? Se for SQL Server, qual é a versão?

Comment: oracle version 4.0.3.16(por isso digo possivelmente sql server) contudo o que interessa é o raciocinio

Comment: "4.0.3" provavelmente se refere ao Oracle SQL Developer, que não é o gerenciador de banco de dados mas sim IDE (integrated development environment) da Oracle.

Comment: Se não me engano Sql Developer usa Sql server, contudo nao sei a versão

Comment: Creio que nem com "analytic functions" pois a "quebra" é complicada. Como seria usada a saída ? Relatório ?

Comment: A forma mais simples de implementar o que solicita é através do uso de cursor. // Outra opção é adaptar o algoritmo _gaps and islands_: sequenciar as linhas usando ANO/MES/DIA como critério de ordenação  (de modo que não haja intervalo), retirar então as linhas com ANALYSIS = 0 e após procurar pelos intervalos.

Comment: Gaps and islands parece promissor

Comment: Ou tentar combinar lad and lead com listagg https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions tentar obter o último zero.

Answer (score 0):

Usando o metodo "start-of-group" é possivel fazer uma espécie de iterador.

```
select 
from   ( select tbl.*,
                count(case when analysis = 0 then 1 end) 
                           over (order by year, mes, dia) as cnt
         from   tbl
       )
where  ...
GROUP BY cnt;
```

Este código não foi feito por mim. por isso um grande obrigado a [Mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921844/its-possible-to-group-by-data-instead-of-column/46922490#46922490).